# Parsing data into expandable list by days of week

Tags: android

```
time=c.optString("time");
            Log.d("time", time);
             tm = Timestamp.valueOf(time);//converting timestamp to day of week

            Log.v("day", String.valueOf(tm.getDay()));

This returns me the day codes..ie 1-Monday to 7-Sunday..
```

Guys I am getting the data and the timestamp from a php SQL server..I want to convert that timestamp into a weekdaay name..like(Monday...)..and accordingly set the data into the 7 day names headers..how do I do this...my expandable list will contain 7 headers..ie 7 days of the week...

Comment: Use an array with the weekday names?

Comment: My problem isnt about the days to be set as headers..my prob is setting the data according to the days..cant use calender class as well..because the server time and the mobile time could be different..